# Make all user profile pictures round

Tags: theming, bootstrap-theme

I am trying to figure out how to apply a class to user profile pictures in Drupal 8 to make the pictures round.

Since I am using Bootstrap 3 I can just apply image-round class in this case, but I am not sure how to add the class to the profile image.

I tried adding a class with the *Field Class* module, but it didn't work.

Comment: Just add the css yourself.. It seems like a lot of effort to go into PHP to add a class that you can duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

In your file of your theme: **"MYTHEME.theme"**

Create ***hook_preprocess_image***

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_image() to add classes to the search form.
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_image(&$variables) {
  ksm ($variables);
    if ($variables['style_name'] == 'thumbnail') {
        $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'image-rounded';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried this like this: 

function isabel_preprocess_image(&$variables) {
  ksm ($variables);
    if ($variables['imagecircle'] == 'thumbnail') {
        $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'img-circle';
    }
}

But for some reason it threw an error on the line :   ksm ($variables);

Comment: that's right. the KSM function is used to show the contents of a variable. To use KSM you must have the DEVEL module installed. Please comment on that line and it will work correctly.